# What are the essential skills for advanced programming with Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm an intermediate level programmer who's interested in lifting my game as far as Delphi programming is concerned. I need to hear from the experts out there.

If I'm about to undertake a Win32 app project using Delphi 2010, what are the essential skills I need to be proficient in (I'd appreciate a list of topics that's neither too brief nor as exhaustive as a TOC in a book)? You can assume that there will be reading from and writing to separate databases and perhaps communications with other system components using web services. Please leave out Unicode compliance as I'm aware of that. Also, is there a good source on the internet for "best practice" programming using Delphi, or is it always a case of "it depends what you're trying to do" (ie. ask individual questions here on SO)? Thanks.

Comment: This question calls for speculation and extended conversation and doesn't really fit with the FAQ.  While I was (and still am) a fan of such questions, I've come to realize that FAQ-writing community are right; These questions don't fit here. They fit on Embarcadero's forums. This is a discussion topic, not a programming question. My short answer: Be really really smart, and really really persistent.

Comment: Had I posted this on Embarcadero's forums I would have limited myself to only the views of the people who participate on those forums. I perceive SO as a wider more representative sample of the programming community. The question doesn't call for 'speculation' or 'extended conversation', it's merely seeking advice from those who are comfortable regarding themselves as 'experts' (refer to Arnaud's answer for a perfect example). Anyway, the question had already been answered (and one accepted) by the time you were faced with the decision, but you just couldn't resist joining the bureaucracy :-)

Comment: If you had 10 upvotes, I wouldn't have voted to close. So I take the 0 as "ambivalence" from the community (during the past 12 hours).  A year ago we would have migrated it to Programmers.SE, the FuzzyWuzzy version of SO. But lately they close this kind of question over there too. It just doesn't fit the format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First advice is to read some part of the RTL/VCL code. Like `Classes.pas SysUtils.pas Graphics.pas Controls.pas`... this is *the* reference when coding in Delphi. Some other part of the code (like SOAP or FireMonkey) is perhaps not such a good reference to learn from... Use the source, Luke!

Some topics, perhaps not specific to Delphi programming, but which I came accross with my team experiment and project code maintenance:

- How Delphi handles memory: there is no garbage collector, but every class instance shall be freed, or have an owner (`TComponent` children);
- Do not forget to handle exceptions: think what may occur (may be the worse), then protect your code with `try .. finally` and `try .. except` blocks (to release resources/memory + handle errors);
- If you have some pre-Delphi 2009 code around, be aware that the string type changed from Ansi to Unicode: some code over the Internet is not Delphi 2010 ready;
- Learn about Unit testing - and use it;
- Learn about n-tier architecture, and do not abuse of the Delphi RAD approach (easy to click and code, but nightmare to maintain if GUI, DB and logic are mixed) - true OOP coding is IMHO mandatory for any serious project.

Comment: +1, *Use the source, Luke!* :-)

Comment: You're right about using the VCL for learning. It contains lots of great code, and even the code that is not so good can be a great example. Problems that arise while using the VCL may guide you to better implementations. When you're capable of detecting these issues and come up with a better solution, you certainly have learned something. :)

Comment: +1 mercie beaucoup, Monsieur. :-)

Answer (score 4):

It's not a case of 'what you're trying to do'. ;)

I don't think that advanced programming has to do with specific knowledge, but rather with the right mindset to grab a problem and come up with a creative solution that is solid and as scalable as it needs to be. Of course you need the knowledge to build it, or at least be able to gain that knowledge by yourself when you have to, but being an (advanced) programmer I think is more about seeing the big picture than having specific programming skills.

Comment: +1 I agree with your philosophy

Answer (score 1):

Use Interfaces!

They are more secure then simple objects because you don't have to free them, the compiler arranges that by using reference counting.

They have the disadvantage of typing the same methods twice (at the interface and at the class section), but this also allows you to hide the class definition inside the implementation section:

```
interface

type
  IJob = interface(IInterface)
  ['{A925F829-60D6-4418-B03A-1655B311D8D9}']
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;

function CreateJob: IJob;

implementation

type
  TJob = class(TInterfacedObject, IJob)
  public
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;

function CreateJob: IJob;
begin
  Result := TJob.Create;
end;

{ TJob }

procedure TJob.DoSomething;
begin
  // do something
end;
```

Notice, that there is no 'Free' in this code, but it is perfectly valid.

Comment: Note that not all objects that implement interfaces are automatically freed! Nevertheless, using interfaces is a great help in lots of situations, one of which is implementing an observer pattern in which the observer can be any class as long as it implements a given interface.

Comment: Just using a particular feature is a great way to become buzzword compliant while making a mess.

Comment: By saying "Use Interfaces!" I mean learn and use interfaces. I don't see any difference in the easiness of making a mess with or without interfaces. It's the responsibility of the developer.